# Booting issue Please help

Tags: mac, bootcamp, windows

When I select Windows to start in my start up disk and restart my computer it doesn't work. It's no bootable disk please insert bootable disk press any key to continue. I was told that I might have rebuild my BCD files on the volume. My question is do I need the installation disk to do that? I don't have the disk anymore. I have music on that side that needs to be finished and save. Please help!!

Comment: Which version of Windows do you have installed? Some versions of Windows can be downloaded for free and burned to a DVD. What is the model/year of your Mac. Usually, you can read the Windows BootCamp partition from OS X. Could you not back up your music from OS X? Which version of OS X do you have installed?

Comment: I have Windows 7 I believe or 8 I can't remember I can't remember. I got my iMac in 2011. I'm still on Maverick for my OSX. I have Fl Studio and it was the crack version I had since 2012 with certain sounds I might not be able to get back.

Answer (score 1):

This answer addresses the situation when you can't repair or fix your Windows OS. Just login to your Mac OS X and search for your Windows OS drive. Then later on from there you can just copy paste all the files you need onto your OS X preferably your desktop. Try to remove the Windows Partition anf make a fresh installation whenever you have access your disc. Hope I helped you :-)